# xyplot trellis multiple pages in same image

Tags: r, trellis

I want to make an xyplot with a large number of groups (on the order of 100).  If I use the default setup it makes so many graphs on one page that I can't interpret what's going on.  But if I naively change the layout it flips through too many plots at once.  As in

```
trellis.device(device="png", filename="glm.png")
p = xyplot(value + hat ~ Time | variable, data=result, type='l', superpose=T, auto.key=T,      layout=c(5, 1))
print(p)
dev.off()
```

What's the best way to have fewer plots per page and still have everything in one image. Either with a scroll bar or a really long image?

Comment: You can try to play with `height` and `width` options in `trellis.device()`.

Comment: You should say what behavior you want. Creating multi-page documents is possibile, although I think not in png format, but we need to know what number of plots per page is less than "too many".

Comment: Thanks guys. Probably 5 per page is about right. layout(5, 1) correctly limits it to 5 per page. But it just spits out the pages one by one.  I tried the newpagpe, more options but they don't make a difference.

Comment: png doesn't support multiple pages; you could use pdf instead. Alternatively, you could write a custom plotting device for knitr so that multiple png files are generated and placed sequentially in a html document. In short, what output format do you want?